# Varnish: Cache Set-Cookie header

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I want to cache the set-cookie header for certain specific cookies. The cookies I want to cache are the same for all users and specific to the page. Is that possible with Varnish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cookie is the same for all users, you can override [the built-in VCL behavior for `Set-Cookie` headers in the `vcl_backend_response`](https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/varnish-builtin-vcl/#dont-cache-responses-with-set-cookie-headers) subroutine as follows:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    if(bereq.url ~ "^/your-page" && beresp.http.Set-Cookie ~ "^yourCookieName=") {
        return(deliver);
    }
}
```

I added the `yourCookieName` check, which you should replace with the name of the actual cookie, to ensure that not every `Set-Cookie` header would be cached.

I also added an extra check to ensure the right URL patterns are matched. Please replace the `^/your-page` regex pattern with the actual URL pattern or perform an exact string match if you only want to match a single page.